# I am exporting PDF from HTML using Baryryvdh/laravel-snappy it's working but zooming out the pdf file

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, controller, laravel-snappy

I am using barryvdh/laravel-snappy using a windows machine.
this is my code in controller:

```
 $pdf = \Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf::loadHTML($req->name)->setPaper('a4')->setOption('margin-bottom, 0)->save(rand().'.pdf');
```

the problem is that the file is creating small in a4 size as the given screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pdf = \Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf::loadHTML($req->name)->setPaper('a4')->setOption('zoom', 1,2822)->save(rand().'.pdf');
```

Comment: why is there need to use zoom option ? and is the value a random guess or how did you come up with it ? thanks in advance